# No help from ?-command

Tags: bugs, information-function

I recently upgraded to Mathematica 10.2, and there seem to be a problem with the help system. When typing

```
?Integrate
```

I get the following output

```
Integrate
System`
CreateUUID["Info-"]
False
False
False
```

(distributed over six cells). If I instead go to the menu, and chose

```
Help -> Wolfram Documentation
```

the help system works as usual. Any ideas about this? If it matters, I run ubuntu 15.04 and I had no problem with version 10.02. A screen shot is included below.

[image: Screen shot showing the problem]

Comment: Try `RebuildPacletData[]`.

Comment: @ilian That indeed made it work. But after restart, I get the same problem again.

Comment: The next step would be to delete the `~/.Mathematica/Paclets` directory.

Comment: @ilian Thanks! Now it continues to work after I restart Mathematica. I'm not sure what to do with the question. If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Since this is a confirmed bug I added the "bugs" tag. I removed the version 10.2 tag because 1) it is not clear whether it is related to this version and 2) we agreed that version information (if known) in bugs posts will be written in the post's header (see [this Meta post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching))

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries What is the status of this bug in version 10.3?

Comment: @QuantumDot I haven't tested it and can't do that right now either, but the answer below seems to indicate that it should be fixed by now.

Comment: @QuantumDot I did not see the bug in 10.3 so far.

Comment: The bug is present in 10.3.1  The bug usually appears after I build documentation files using Workbench.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a bug in the paclet manager, which can cause the autoloading for certain system symbols to stop working (in this case, `CreateUUID` malfunctioned, also breaking `Information` which uses it).

The problem has already been fixed in the development version. For now, the recommended workaround is to delete the `$UserBasePacletsDirectory`, which is typically located in `~/.Mathematica/Paclets` on Linux.