# Weird variable report

Tags: core-language

All, What does this mean when it shows up in your notebook?

?f

f

Global`

CreateUUID["Info-"]

False

False

False

?x

x

Global`

CreateUUID["Info-"]

False

False

False

What has happened? Quitting the local kernel cures the problem, but I wonder why something like this occurs. It happens on one of student computers as well, so I'd like to able to explain.

Here's what I was doing right before it happened.

```
f[x_, y_] = Abs[Abs[x] - Abs[y]] - Abs[x] - Abs[y];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Then I tried:

```
Plot3D[{f[x, y],0},{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

And it didn't plot. That's when I tried ?f, ?x.

Comment: OS and version number, please.

Comment: @J.M.isback. OS X 10.10.5, MM 10.2.0.0.

Comment: I cannot repeat the problem on OS X 10.11, Mathematica 10.2.0.0

Comment: I suspect this was caused by the Suggestions bar, try disabling it. If the issue persists, also try the steps from [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94165).