# ?f returns a weird result

Tags: notebooks, kernel

Anybody know why something like this happens?

[image]

Comment: All I get is `Global`f`.

Comment: OS and version, please.

Comment: Your situation appears to be similar to a bug in Mathematica 10.2, it was object of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94165/no-help-from-command).

Comment: @J.M. OSX 10.11.1. Mathematica 10.3.0.0

Comment: Looks like some kind of Notebook corruption. Try it in another notebook and also in a Kernel session.

Comment: Strange, I expected this to be resolved in 10.3. Nevertheless the [workaround](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94167/145) from the previous question should still apply: shut down Mathematica and delete the contents of your `$HOME/Library/Mathematica/Paclets` directory.